# Querying on recordID results in "Internal server error"

Tags: objective-c, cloudkit

When I execute this code:

```
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];
CKRecordID  *recordID  = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName: @"95263874-C860-4190-A2BB-08B3E652B7AA"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", @"recordID", [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID: recordID action: CKReferenceActionNone]];
CKQuery     *query     = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType: @"Case" predicate: predicate];
[publicDatabase performQuery: query inZoneWithID: nil completionHandler: ^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
}];
```

I get this error:

> <CKError 0x618000042670: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2000); server message = "Internal server error"; uuid = 122AB9AA-6949-442D-B9D7-736A5B7D2EE5; container ID = "iCloud.net.xxxxxxx">

However, if I change the predicate to this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"PatientName = %@ ", @"Doe, John"];
```

The retrieve works correctly. I have verified that John Doe has record name that I am searching for.  I have also tried toggling the iCloud "Capability" in the project settings. I have spent hours and hours on this issue and have tried many variations.  Nothing works!

Comment: If you know the record id, you should get the record using `CKFetchRecordsOperation` or at least use `fetchRecordWithID:completionHandler:`. Either is better than using `performQuery` when you know the record id.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and it works!  If you make this an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've marked Record ID as queryable for this record type in the [CloudKit Dashboard](http://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard).

Select your record type and click on "Metadata Indexes". Check the Query checkbox next to the Record ID field and this error should go away.

Aside from that, rmaddy's answer is right- if you're just trying to fetch a record by its identifier you should use `CKFetchRecordsOperation` instead of a query.

Comment: The CloudKit server folks are looking into this as a potential bug- this may not be anything your code is doing wrong. However, you'll still need to mark that property as queryable, and rmaddy's suggestion of using `CKFetchRecordsOperation` is still the better way to find a record by its ID.

Comment: The table is queryable, so that, unfortunately, is not the solution.  I will convert over to use that @maddy suggested.

Comment: It seems odd that a two year old product should be returning "Internal server errors" @farttronix.